# how to correctly edit htaccess to cloak URL?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this directory on my site

```
example.net/cube
```

there is nothing there except a htaccess file that is supposed to redirect the user to this other directory

```
example.net:5000/newdir
```

but the user should still see example.net/cube on their address bar.

This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ ../:5000/newdir
```

but it doesnt seem to do anything. What is the deal here?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do add samples of input and to whom that should redirected/rewritten in your question. That will help us to understand your question better manner

Comment: I am not sure `../:5000/newdir` will work as intended (at least when I test the equivalent in HTML, this resolves to `https://example.net/:5000/newdir`) - I think you might need to use the absolute URL here, and combine it with `P` flag for proxy functionality, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by means of an internal rewrite as your apporach implements. Reason is that the target URL points to a completely separate host from the point if view of the http server.

You could implement an external redirection, but that would change the URL visible in the clients address bar.

Your only option is to use the http server's proxy module *if that module is installed and usable* . For the apache http server that means that you have to install the modules `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http`. Or make sure they are installed and usable for your http host.

If so you have two options:

---

You can use the proxy module inside your http server's host configuration for the http host "example.com" listening at port 80:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /cube http://example.com:5000/newdir
ProxyPassReverse /cube http://example.com:5000/newdir
```

Or slightly changed inside a `<Location ...>` block for the `/cube` folder in the http host configuration:

```
<Location "/cube/">
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass http://example.com:5000/newdir/
    ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:5000/newdir/
</Location>
```

---

As an alternative you can use the proxy module embedded in the rewriting module. Either in the central configuration of your http server's host or a distributed configuration file (".htaccess") in the top level `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of that host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?cube(.*)$ http://example.com:5000/newdir$1 [P]
```

Or slightly changed in a distributed configuration file inside the `/cube` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:5000/newdir/$1 [P]
```

---

Either way you will need to start consulting the module's documentation. As typical for OpenSource software it is of excellent quality and comes with great examples:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html